# Display buffer without transferring to the buffer

Tags: display-buffer

I am using `(display-buffer buffer)` and `(pop-to-buffer buffer)`.  The latter puts the cursor in the buffer.  Although I want to show the buffer, I want to stay in the buffer I am working on rather than have `pop-to-buffer` switch to another buffer.

Comment: What do you want to do with `pop-to-buffer` that `display-buffer` doesn't do? Most of the work of `pop-to-buffer` is to select the window that `display-buffer` found or created.

Comment: `(display-buffer buffer)` does what you requested: it displays `buffer` without selecting its window. But presumably you meant something else - unclear question.

Comment: The problem occurs when starting emacs.  I get the scratch buffer, but the additional buffer does not show up below the scratch buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem occurs when starting emacs.  I get the scratch buffer...

Use `emacs-startup-hook` to run code after other startup activities (such as displaying the scratch buffer) have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have two windows open, and you're looking to change the buffer displayed in the inactive window?

This will do that:

```
(let ((original-window (selected-window))
      (next-window (next-window)))
  (select-window next-window)
  (switch-to-buffer "new-buffer")
  (select-window original-window))
```

Comment: Because I call the function in my init file, I end up with emacs showing the created buffer.  Would like that the scratch buffer shows up as the current buffer.   Beneath it I get the new buffer.  But control is still on the scratch buffer.

Comment: I'm not especially sure what you're looking for. Can you give some more detail as to what's going on, and what you want?